# Animating CALayer upon change of custom property

Tags: c#, animation, xamarin.ios, calayer

I'm trying to trigger animation of a CALayer upon change of a custom property. When I change the radius of my circle, I want the layer to automatically trigger animation of it. In Objective-C this is possible ([like in this example](http://blog.moonshine-project.com/en/2010/03/14/implicit-animation-of-custom-calayer-properties/)) by setting the `@dynamic` attribute to the property and overriding the `actionForKey:` method, which in turn sets up the animation.

```
public class MyCircle : CALayer
{
    [Export ("radius")]
    public float Radius { get; set; }

    public MyCircle ()
    {
        Radius = 200;
        SetNeedsDisplay ();
    }

    [Export ("initWithLayer:")]
    public MyCircle (CALayer other) : base (other) 
    { }

    public override void Clone (CALayer other)
    {
        base.Clone (other);
        MyCircle o = other as MyCircle;
        Radius = o.Radius;
    }

    public CABasicAnimation MakeAnimationForKey (String key)
    {
        CABasicAnimation animation = CABasicAnimation.FromKeyPath (key);
        animation.From = PresentationLayer.ValueForKey (new NSString (key));
        animation.Duration = 1;
        return animation;
    }

    [Export ("actionForKey:")]
    public override NSObject ActionForKey (string key)
    {
        switch (key.ToString ())
        {
            case "radius":
                return MakeAnimationForKey (key);
            default:
                return base.ActionForKey (key);
        }
    }

    [Export ("needsDisplayForKey:")]
    static bool NeedsDisplayForKey (NSString key)
    {
        switch (key.ToString ())
        {
            case "radius":
                return true;
            default:
                return CALayer.NeedsDisplayForKey (key);
        }
    }

    public override void DrawInContext (CGContext ctx)
    {
        // draw circle based in radius
    }
}
```

However, in my C#/Monotouch code, "radius" is never sent to ActionForKey when the value is changed. In a previous question ([Animate a custom property using CoreAnimation in Monotouch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544591/animate-a-custom-property-using-coreanimation-in-monotouch)) the answer and supplied sample code is based on the custom property animation being invoked manually (which I don't desire).

Is the (by me) desired behavior supported by Monotouch? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "the custom property animation being invoked manually" for the sample code in the other answer?

Comment: In your sample code on GitHub, you set up all the animations explicitly in AppDelegate/FinishedLaunching. But in the Objective-C code I linked to, the ActionForKey is invoked when the properties in the CALayer subclass are changed. The latter is a neater, since the CALayer subclass itself becomes responsible for the transitions (instead of the caller) and more general with reduced code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a constructor in your code:

```
[Export ("initWithLayer:")]
public MyCircle (CALayer other)
    : base (other)
{
}
```

I'm not sure it'll fix your problem, but it's worth a try :)

Comment: I've added that, without success (according to your answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579532/calayer-initwithlayer-bound-to-default-constructor-by-mistake-can-i-override-t)

Comment: Hm, I can't see why it doesn't work. Can you create a complete test project I can try out?

Comment: https://github.com/frogge/sandbox/tree/master/MyCircle

ActionForKey is never called with "radius" (which would generate the animation).

Comment: I'm running into this same exact situation. I have a property on my CALayer who's setter is invoking Will/DidChangeValue
WillChangeValue("Offset");
_offset = value;
 DidChangeValue("Offset");

Yet ActionForKey is never fired. Has there been any resolution on this issue? I can't seem to find any official documentation or notes on how to use ActionForKey in Xamarin...